# Preload a sound using Javascript and/or HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I'm creating a Joomla! component where I want a specific sound to be played on mouse click.

I have the following code:

```
        var context = new AudioContext(); 
        var sound; 
        var playSound = context.createBufferSource();
        var getSound = new XMLHttpRequest();
        getSound.open("GET", "clapping.wav", true);
        getSound.responseType = "arraybuffer";
        getSound.onload = function() {
        context.decodeAudioData(getSound.response, function(buffer){
        sound = buffer;     
        });     
        }
        getSound.send();
        getSound.send();
        setTimeout(function(){  
        playSound.buffer = electro;
        playSound.connect(context.destination);         
        },3500); 

        jQuery("#bgchanger").click(function() {     
        playSound.start(0);     
        }
```

This works fine however the problem I'm facing is that the sound is playing after some seconds when I click the button and not immediately so I want it to play directly.

Comment: Do not show the play button unless audio is completely loaded.

Comment: I'm not using a play button. I'm using a button that will do something else and will also play the sound on click. The thing is that the sound isnt geting loaded at all until I click that button. Even if I put playSound.buffer = sound;
playSound.connect(context.destination);  on a timer and then put the  playSound.start(0); on the button click event I'm having the same behaviour.

Comment: Simple option will be to load the audio before button click. Makes sense ?

Comment: Please check my updated code. This code supposedly gives time to load the file but it still doesnt play directly. Am I missing something here?

Comment: How could you decide the required time to load the audio file, Can you ?

Comment: It doesnt matter if I put 10 seconds or 1 minute and then wait before I click the button for another minute. The result is the same. The file is 2.5MB and I'm trying this locally so it should take some milliseconds and not minutes.

Comment: Need to see entire code of yours so that one could debug it.

Comment: The JS file is quite long. and so is the actual php page. Do you want me to copy paste the button and some of the JS or?

Comment: Relevant executable will do..

Comment: :D Human makes errors !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well feeling a bit dumb I just noticed why this is happening... They sent me the file some minutes ago and I just noticed that it has a 2.5 seconds mute at the beggining... I can see on the debug screen on Chrome that the file is downloaded after 52ms when I load the page.